# How can I apply the Fody Equals to all classes in my assembly?

Tags: .net, fody

Is there a way to bind the [Equals] Attribute of Fody-Equals to all classes in an assembly and just somehow ignore the classes that should not contain the Fody-Equals implementation?

Comment: Have you ever found an answer to this question?